# Compilation Error with Maven on Intellij: Module not found: processed.jcommander

Tags: java, selenium, maven, javafx, intellij-14

I was developing some small program using selenium and javaFX. everything was going fine, when i tried my code on selenium on a project and on a JavaFX project separatedly. When i put the code together and imported all dependecies to maven, and tried to run, it keep showing this error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------[ERROR] module not found: processed.jcommander[ERROR] module not found: processed.async.http.client
```

I don't know what are those modules, they were not dependecies and are not used in the code. What those modules are and why compilation error?

Here is my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DedoDoDida</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.18.6</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.10</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>20-ea+11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>19</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried already searching on internet and i am stuck on this problem for 2 days already, i was giving up this project but i decided to try stackoverflow. Probably some easy thing to solve that i am not being able to solve.

Comment: Offtopic: The current version of the `javafx-maven-plugin` is `0.0.8`.  The current non-early access (no `-ea` in the version) of JavaFX is `19`.

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` then you can delete it and run the application non-modular, see [openjfx.io getting started](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  If you want a modular project, require all of the correct modules in your `module-info.java`, see [understanding modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), and provide the fully qualified (by module) name when specifying the `mainClass` to the javafx-maven-plugin.

Comment: @jewelsea what you mean by that? What version should i use? Sorry i don't understand

Comment: @jewelsea i tried to run without this module-info and it shows another error: Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application. But the maven are importing javafx this makes no sense

Comment: @jewelsea i will read this understanding modules to try to understand. The getting started of openjfx.io i have readed already and tryied many different aproaches, none have worked. Tryied creating with archetype from beggining ant nothing too.

Comment: *"What version should i use?"* -> You should use the versions suggested in the comment, `javafx-maven-plugin` `0.0.8`, instead of what you have (which is `0.0.8).  Similarly, JavaFX versions should be `19`, not `20-ea+11`.  That is not the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. I created a new project using the Idea new JavaFX project, which is what you did. And added the dependencies to `webdrivermanager` and `selenium-java` as you have and the resultant application ran fine.  So the error is in something that you are not showing.

Comment: @jewelsea maybe the problem is the archetype from intellij. In this new version of intellij the way to create a project from archetype is a bit different from the openjfx.io doc - And my intellij is not saving the archetype on any of the catalog (internal or default local). Maybe is a problem with my intellij? When it create a project from this archetype showed on the openjfx it is being created empty and basic, no classes and no source code. Maybe i should create another question for that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because the Java Platform Module definitions used for the `4.7.1` version of Selenium software that you are using appear (to me) to be broken.

I'm working with the pom.xml you have in your application updated for:

> - The current version of the javafx-maven-plugin is 0.0.8.
> - The current non-early access (no -ea in the version) of JavaFX is 19.

And the [hello world program from the selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

```
package dev.selenium.hello;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HelloSelenium {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://selenium.dev");

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell (and I can't really find documentation on this), so maybe this isn't even supported at the moment, to use Selenium in a modular application, you need the following modules in your `module-info.java`.  These were suggested by my IDE when I tried to compile the above program.

```
requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.api;
requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver;
```

Once that was done, a subsequent `mvn:compile` gives the errors from the question:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] module not found: processed.jcommander
[ERROR] module not found: processed.async.http.client
```

These modules are not in the transitive dependencies for selenium, so the selenium modules are broken.  There are maven dependencies on the artifacts, so you can see jcommander and async-http-client jars in the library dependencies that Maven brings in, however those jars do not provide any module information, so their module names should be derived from the jar file names as "automatic modules".  This means they would be referenced from a `module-info.java` as:

```
requires jcommander;
requires async.http.client;
```

But they are not referenced using these names.

The selenium-chrome-driver jar has:

```
module org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver {
    ...
    requires org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver;
    ...
}
```

The selenium-remote-driver jar, has:

```
module org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver {
    ...
    requires processed.async.http.client;
    requires processed.jcommander;
    ...
}
```

So those are the wrong names, the modules with the `processed.` prefix do not exist, so the simple `HelloSelenium` application is not usable if you define `module-info.java`.

The only workaround I can advise for now is to make your application non-modular by ***not*** defining a `module-info.java` (i.e. delete the `module-info.java` file if you have one in your project.).

However, because JavaFX needs to be on the module path, you then also need to either:

1. Use a JDK which includes JavaFX (e.g. ["Full JDK" from liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-19-current)), (*this is the option I recommend*) OR
2. Add VM options to set the module path and add the JavaFX modules at compile and execution time (as specified at [openjfx.io](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-19-current)).

I also advise [filing a bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) for the selenium project to fix their broken module definitions in the selenium-remote-driver jar.

- Note: I don't know how the selenium project bug reporting process works, so I guessed the issue link, it might be something else for this error, but my recommendation is to try that.
- In filing a bug report you can link back to this post.
- If you file a bug report post a link to it here either by editing this answer or posting a comment.

Comment: The solution still not worked for me. If you try the hello world from selenium mixed with the hello world of javafx or the model that they provide, i think will still not work. When i try to use the JavaFX library it keeps on the error with the libericaJDK too. Maybe the LibericaJDK does not have the same JavaFX i don't know. I will try the second option. The error now is that the javaFX Runtime Enviroment components was not found, when i not use the module-info.java making the app non-modular. But the code at least compiles wich is good. But this error is at runtime now.

Comment: Actually i have no clue how to do that 2 - Add VM options to set the module path and add the JavaFX modules at compile and execution time (as specified at openjfx.io). I setted the enviroment variable on windows, downloaded the JAVAFX lib, put the VM Option 'javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modulesjavafx.controls,javafx.fxml Main.java' and still not worked. Now i got the error 'Error: Could not find or load main class javac
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javac'

Comment: You probably did not select the "Full JDK" when you downloaded liberica. On the download page I linked, where it says "package", select "Full JDK", not the default "Standard JDK".

Comment: If you set VM options instead you need a space between --add-modules and the modules you add.  But you could run it through maven instead without setting the VM options as the plugin will handle that for you.  See openjfx.io section "Getting started -> JavaFX and IntelliJ -> Non-modular with Maven -> 3. Run the project", don't worry about stuff in the earlier sections they already work for you.  Then follow instructions.

Comment: "Open the Maven Projects window (View -> Tool Windows -> Maven) and click on HelloFX -> Plugins -> compiler -> compiler:compile to compile the project, and click on HelloFX -> Plugins -> javafx -> javafx:run to execute the project."

Comment: thank you for the perfect explanation! You have perfect understanding of the problem while i was lost. Actually the way i solved was using your second option! I used this tutorial found here : [link](https://ashley-tharp.medium.com/solved-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-run-this-application-ec4779eb796d)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers didn't mention this, I wanted to put this out over here that 4.6.0 version is working fine and not giving a similar error.
In case you don't require specific enhancements/bug-fixes introduced from 4.7.x, you can use 4.6.0.
I was also using 4.7.2 earlier but rolled back to 4.6.0 and it worked like a charm.